# Load image from resource in xaml

Tags: wpf, image, resources, resourcedictionary

I have a xaml resource linked in this way

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="AudioPitchShiftStyle.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

    </ResourceDictionary>

</Window.Resources>
```

insite AudioPitchShiftStyle.xaml I have put this declaration

```
<Image Source="img/play.png" x:Key="play" />
```

How can I achieve the ImageBitmap by code using the source key ?

Answer (score 2):

you can take from Resource dictionaries.

```
<Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary 
                  Source="Resources/MyResourceDictionary.xaml">
                </ResourceDictionary>
                <ResourceDictionary 
                  Source="Resources/OthersStyle.xaml">
                </ResourceDictionary>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Image Source="/WPFDemo;component/Images/AddResourceDictionary.jpg"></Image>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but I meant using C#. Anyway I figured how take it.

```c#
ResourceDictionary dicto = this.Resources.MergedDictionaries[0];
Image myImage = (Image)dicto["play"];
img.Source = myImage.Source;
```

Thank you the same :-)